# Looping through plots, then taking sum of a select number of plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, physics, python-xarray

I am trying to create a function that plots EOFs and loops through each mode. This part is fine and I had no trouble getting out a plot of the 12 EOFs.

However, now I would like to sum across the first three EOF plots, the first six EOF plots, the first nine EOF plots, and then all EOF plots to generate a plot at the end of each of row to show a cumulative sum for the first three, first six, etc.

Attached is what my EOF plot looks like right now. I want to add summations in a fourth column.

[image: EOFs plot from Function]

I have tried creating a new loop that is basically an 'if statement' saying that if the column is the last to sum the previous EOF modes and add a subplot for these (in column 4).

Unfortunately, I am not seeing any change in my plot when doing this. I have tried changing to sum across i (which I would interpret as going through each mode) and even an explicit calling of each mode, which ends up producing an error. I am having a hard time figuring out how to sum across the eofs from the for loop.

Here is the code:

```
def GPH_EOFs_plot(eof12):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
    for i in range(0,12):
        clevs = np.linspace(-75, 75, 11)
        proj = ccrs.Orthographic(central_longitude=-90, central_latitude=90)
        ncols = 4
        nrows = 3
        ax = plt.subplot(ncols,nrows,i+1, projection = proj)
        ax.coastlines(color='grey', linewidth=1.0)
        ax.set_global()
        eofs = eof12.sel(mode=i)
        eofs_2d = eofs.squeeze()
        eofs_2d.plot.contourf(ax=ax, levels=clevs, cmap=plt.cm.RdBu_r, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), add_colorbar=False)
        if ncols == 3:
            eof_sum = sum(i)
            eof_sum.plot.contourf(ax=ax, levels=clevs, cmap=plt.cm.RdBu_r, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), add_colorbar=True)


    plt.savefig("EOFs_fromfunction.png",format='png')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with the code and I cannot test this, but this is an attempt.

First, your index `i` is being used for the `mode` in `eof12.sel(mode=i)` and for the subplot index. When you were plotting only the modes, this was fine. Now, you have a new column and the indices will have different meanings.

I will call them `imode` and `isubplt`.

Next, you have an extra subplot everytime `i % 3 == 2`. This is your marker. Every time this happens, `isubplt` has to increase, but not `imode`.

Finally, you need to set up your fourth column, by creating a new `ax`.

What is missing here is the code to calculate the sum. From what you said, you want to initialize `eof_sum` to zeros and add each `eof_2d` to it. You must fill this code.

```py
def GPH_EOFs_plot(eof12):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
    eof_sum = ### TODO: initialize eof_sum to all zeros ###
    isubplt = 1 # subplots start at 1
    for imode in range(0,12):
        clevs = np.linspace(-75, 75, 11)
        proj = ccrs.Orthographic(central_longitude=-90, central_latitude=90)
        ncols = 4
        nrows = 4 # now you will have four lines
        ax = plt.subplot(ncols, nrows, isubplt, projection = proj)
        isubplt += 1 # skip to the next subplot
        ax.coastlines(color='grey', linewidth=1.0)
        ax.set_global()
        eofs = eof12.sel(mode=imode)
        eofs_2d = eofs.squeeze()
        eof_sum = ### TODO: accumulate this plot ###
        eofs_2d.plot.contourf(ax=ax, levels=clevs, cmap=plt.cm.RdBu_r, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), add_colorbar=False)
        if imode % 3 == 2:
            # create the fourth subplot
            ax = plt.subplot(ncols, nrows, isubplt, projection = proj)
            isubplt += 1 # skip to the next subplot
            ax.coastlines(color='grey', linewidth=1.0)
            ax.set_global()
            eof_sum.plot.contourf(ax=ax, levels=clevs, cmap=plt.cm.RdBu_r, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), add_colorbar=True)

    plt.savefig("EOFs_fromfunction.png",format='png')
```